# Images not being drawn on HTML5 canvas everytime

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on a web app with which users can construct a mesh containing simple objects (rectangular shaped) that can hold text and/or images. Users can create as many of these objects as they like, and in each object that can hold an image, upload one of their own. The app is online  if you'd like to test it: [goalcandy.com](http://goalcandy.com) *(use **demo@demo.com** / **demo** for the email and pswd fields to log in)*.

Once they finalize their work, they can convert that mesh to PNG. This is done by first drawing everything that's on the mesh on an HTML canvas, which is afterward converted to a PNG image, locally.

When needing to draw the array of existing images onto the canvas, I first have to preload them, which I do like this:

```
query = [];   // array with paths to the image

var count = query.length,
    images = [],
    loaded = 0;

for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].onload = function(){
        loaded++;
        if (loaded == count)
                           drawOnCanvas();
    };
    images[i].src = query[i];
}

function drawOnCanvas() {
        // draw the images onto the canvas
}
```

The problem with all of this is that on a slow, "tired" computer, the PNG sometimes turns out blank in the spaces where some user-uploaded images are supposed to be, because the images don't get drawn onto the canvas. As if they haven't finished downloading. On a good, fast computer, this doesn't happen. How can I solve this, and why does it happen? Considering that I've already attached a handler for the "load" event, I don't see the logic...

Comment: `GET http://goalcandy.com/workspaces/w25022a4a2d3592.png 404 (Not Found) view:57`

Comment: Sorry about that, try again please.